# В некоторых случаях нет элемента парсинга и тогда выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, парсер, telebot, requests, beautiful-soup

Я новичок в этом деле и как первый проект я решил написать парсер информации с аниме сайта `jut.su/user/AngelicKing/anime`. Но проблема в том, что при получении оценок аниме от пользователей получаю ошибку, в случае если человек просто отметил, но не поставил отметку.

```
u_animes = soup_anime.find_all('div', class_='aaname')
u_actives = soup_anime.find_all('span', class_='av_active')
u_animelist = ""
u_animeative = []
u_number = 0 
for u_active in u_actives:
    u_animeative.append(u_active.text)
for u_anime in u_animes:
    u_number += 1
    u_animelist += f"{u_number}. {u_anime.text}\nОценка: {u_animeative[u_number-1]}\n\n\t\t\t\t"
        result = ""
```

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, отступы и добавьте ссылку на страницу с такими элементами.

Comment: прошу прощение, забыл. 
jut.su

Comment: А если быть точнее jut.su/user/AngelicKing/anime